# How to convert a Tree View list in HTML into a textual content using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Input: TreeView inHTML Page
Output: Normal Eng Language Representation (like Nested Loops)

eg:

input:

```
Animals
   Birds
   Mammals
     Elephant
     Mouse
Reptiles
Plants
   Flowers
     Rose
     Tulip
Trees
```

output:

```
Begin Node Animal
       {

        Birds
        Begin Node Mammals
         {
                   Elements
```

Note: Please look at the below enclosed HTML file which I tried. Please help me out as soon as possible.

```
    <title>A Tree from HTML Lists</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family:verdana;
            font-size:12px;
        }
        li {
                cursor:pointer; 
            display:block; 
            width:100px;
        }
        .Folder {
        }
        .ExpandCollapse {
            float:left;
            margin-right:5px;
            width:8px;
        }
        ul {
            list-style-type:none;
        }
        #ExpandCollapseFolder1
        {
        display: none;
        }
        #ExpandCollapseFolder2
        {
        display: none;
        }
        #ExpandCollapseFolder3
        {
        display: none;
        }

    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
            function takeAction(e) {
            var node = e.srcElement == undefined ? e.target : e.srcElement;

            var id = node.getAttribute("id"); 
            if (id != null && id.indexOf("Folder") > -1) {
                if (node.innerHTML == "-") {
                    node.innerHTML = "+";

                    document.getElementById("ExpandCollapse" + id).style.display = "none";

                } else if (node.innerHTML == "+") {
                    node.innerHTML = "-";
                    document.getElementById("ExpandCollapse" + id).style.display = "block";

                }
            }
        }
            /* function doFunction()
        {
        //alert(document.getElementById("ExpandCollapseFolder1").style.display);
        var list=document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];

        var a=list.getElementsByTagName("li")[5].innerHTML;
        alert(a);

        }               
            */
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
        function doFunction() {

  var tree = document.getElementById("tree");
  var lists = [ tree ];
  var txt="";
  var txt1="";


  for (var i = 0; i < tree.getElementsByTagName("ul").length; i++)
  {

    lists[lists.length] = tree.getElementsByTagName("ul")[i];
    list=document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {

        var item = lists[i].lastChild;
        txt1=txt1+item.value;

        txt1=txt1+"\n \t"+list.getElementsByTagName("li")[i].innerHTML;

    }

  }


  document.getElementById("writeArea").value=txt+txt1;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height:600px;width:500px;float:left;">
    <ul  onclick="takeAction(event);" class="tree" id="tree">
        <li><div id="Folder1" class="ExpandCollapse">+</div><div class="Folder">Folder 1</div></li>

            <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder1">

            <li>Item 1</li> 
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>

        <li><div id="Folder2" class="ExpandCollapse">+</div><div class="Folder">Folder 2</div></li>
        <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder2">
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li><div id="Folder3" class="ExpandCollapse">+</div><div class="Folder">Folder 3</div></li>
            <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder3">
                <li>Item 6</li>
                <li>Item 7</li>
                <li>Item 8</li>
                <li>Item 9</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <li>Item 10</li>
        <li>Item 11</li>
        <li>Item 12</li>
        <li>Item 13</li>
    </ul>

    <button type="button" onclick="doFunction();">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:600px;width:700px;float:right;">
    <textarea id="writeArea" rows="40" cols="85">
    </textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Someone from the users..please reply to it asap. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi user2893512, asking for replies ASAP is not going to get your question answered any faster and even considered rude by some members. You posted your question only 17 minutes ago, have some patience. I've edited you question a bit in an attempt to make it better to understand, but I still do not really understand what you are trying to achieve. You should explain your goal and your specific problems a bit better.

Comment: This looks like you want us to do your homework. As explained in the help pages, a good question should "include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: I agree that my question is not much clear. . Now I don't want to make a debate here. The above code is completely written by me. Its not like I have done nothing. I gave my best. If possible could you people try to run the HTML. 

The HTML page is splitted into two pages. On one side of the html page consists of a Tree View (unordered list items) and a button. When user clicks on this button, It has to update the right side TEXTAREA with Tree View in a generic english language like eg FORTRAN

Comment: I apologize, I simply had not seen your JavaScript code.

Comment: Can I expect solution or suggestion by EOD. Please consider this question with high priority as it is very important and urgent to me. Please don't consider my comment in a wrong way. I hope the question is not much difficult/hard..